# Does approving on an step means the record will execute the Final Approval Actions and not go to the next steps?

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have an approval process that on the first step sends a quote to our CRO if the Quote Term is less than 10 months.
My next steps involve other criteria that go to other members of the executive team.

I was expecting that when my CRO approved the Quote, for the quote to execute the Final Approval Steps and not go to the next steps BUT that is NOT happening; what I get instead is the approval going to the next Approval step.
Is this salesforce expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, indeed.

The approvals are designed in a way that enables you to set it up in different ways. Let me provide you with some example scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**
For some customers, manager1 has to approve if under 10 months, and if over 10 months, both manager1 and manager2 have to approve (in that order).
Entry criteria for step 1: none (manager1 always has to approve)
Entry criteria for step 2: term over 10 months
Entry criteria for step 3: term over 24 months

**Scenario 2:**
For other customers (like you), manager1 has to approve if under 10 months, and if over 10 months, ONLY manager2 has to approve.
Entry criteria for step 1: term under 10 months
Entry criteria for step 2: term over 10 months

Lastly, on every step (except the last one) you will see an additional option: “else” This is explaining what happens if a record does not meet the criteria to enter this step. You will need to set this up according to your requirement.
The options are:

- Go to the next step
- Approve record
- Reject record

For your requirement, set this to 'Go to the next step' on step 1.